# Interpolate within points in a vector

Tags: r, statistics, interpolation

Vector V1 contains 56 observations for X, and vector BS contains a bootstrapped sample of V1 of length 100000. I would like to interpolate linearly within points in BS to fill in any missing values. For example, V1 contains no 0.27 values, and hence neither does BS. But BS would contain a few 0.28 and 0.26. I would like the interpolation to create a few 0.27 values and add those to BS. And so on for any missing values within the two extremes in the vector.

```
V1 <- c(0.18, 0.2, 0.24, 0.35, -0.22, -0.17, 0.28, -0.28, -0.14, 0.03, 0.87, -0.2, 0.06, -0.1, -0.72, 0.18, 0.01, 0.31, -0.36, 0.61, -0.16, -0.07, -0.13, 0.01, -0.09, 0.26, -0.14, 0.08, -0.62, -0.2, 0.3, -0.21, -0.11, 0.05, 0.06, -0.28, -0.27, 0.17, 0.42, -0.05, -0.15, 0.05, -0.07, -0.22, -0.34, 0.16, 0.34, 0.1, -0.12, 0.24, 0.45, 0.37, 0.61, 0.9, -0.25, 0.02)
BS <- sample(V1, 100000, replace=TRUE)
```

The `approxfun` functions do not help as are for interpolating within data sets. Have found a few questions/answers covering interpolating within different data sets, but not within one data set. Thank you for your help.

EDIT: please note I do not want to fit a normal distribution (or any other) to create those points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `approx()` (or `approxfun()`) to do this by treating `BS` as the y-coordinate and using sequential x-coordinates:

```
set.seed(1L); BS <- sample(V1,1e5L,T);
res <- approx(seq_along(BS),BS,n=length(BS)*2L-1L)$y;
```

The specification of `n` here is important. It ensures that exactly one interpolated value will be produced halfway between each adjacent pair of input values.

---

Here's a plot of an excerpt of the result, centered around the first occurrence of an adjacent pair of 0.26 and 0.28:

```
i <- which(BS[-length(BS)]==0.26 & BS[-1L]==0.28)[1L];
j <- i*2L-1L;
xlim <- c(j-6L,j+8L);
ylim <- c(-1,1);
xticks <- seq(xlim[1L],xlim[2L]);
yticks <- seq(ylim[1L],ylim[2L],0.05);
plot(NA,xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim,xlab='res index',ylab='y',axes=F,xaxs='i',yaxs='i');
abline(v=xticks,col='lightgrey');
abline(h=yticks,col='lightgrey');
axis(1L,xticks,cex.axis=0.7);
axis(2L,yticks,sprintf('%.02f',round(yticks,2L)),las=1L,cex.axis=0.7);
x <- seq(xlim[1L],xlim[2L],2L); y <- BS[seq(i-3L,len=8L)];
points(x,y,pch=16L,col='red',xpd=NA);
x <- seq(xlim[1L],xlim[2L]); y <- res[x];
points(x,y,pch=4L,cex=1.2,col='blue',xpd=NA);
text(x+0.24,y+0.03,y,cex=0.7,xpd=NA);
legend(xlim[1L]+1.5,0.87,c('input value','interpolated'),col=c('red','blue'),pch=c(16L,4L));
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Impressive. Thanks a lot! Many things I do not understand. I interpret that `approx(seq_along(BS),BS,n=length(BS)*2L-1L)` interpolates between a) a vector made of a sequence between 1 and 100,000, and b) vector BS. Don't see how can that produce the desired result (yet it does). Also how does setting n=199,999 make the interpolated values be produced halfway between adjacent pairs of input values? And what is `$y`? Sorry so many questions, have been analyzing your response and the `approxfun` documentation for over an hour and got nowhere.

Comment: The `approx()` functions linearly interpolate in two-dimensional space. First note that the `n` argument represents the total number of output points. To get one interpolation between each adjacent pair of input points requires 99,999 additional points, plus the 100,000 input points equals 199,999. Now, you should visualize the 2D points formed from the `seq_along(BS)` sequence as x and the vector `BS` as y. Visualizing the 2D points should make it clear that the points that interpolate between adjacent input points will lie halfway between them, with respect to both x and y dimensions.

Comment: The syntax `$y` is standard R syntax for indexing out a component of a list, a column of a data.frame, or an entry of an environment by its name. This is how we can extract the interpolated y coordinates from the return value of the `approx()` function, which is a list with two components `x` and `y`. See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html.